# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting this error "Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in" out of code snippet
"searchcar.php"

```
$modelmake = $_POST['model_make'];
$result = $db->select('car_information','*', 'Model_Make LIKE \'%$modelmake%\''); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo 'Model'.$row['model_make'];
}
```

here is code snippet from "database.php" the select function

```
 public function select(
        $table,
        $fields = '*',
        $where = '1=1',
        $order = '',
        $limit = '',
        $desc = false,
        $limitBegin = 0,
        $groupby = null,
        $monitoring = false
    ) //monitoring is set to true to view the actual query
    {
//  $query ='SELECT ' . $fields . ' FROM ' . $table ;
    $query = 'SELECT ' . $fields . ' FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE ' . $where;

        if (!empty($groupby)) {
            $query .= ' GROUP BY ' . $groupby;
        }

        if (!empty($order)) 
        {
            $query .= ' ORDER BY ' . $order;

            if ($desc) 
            {
                $query .= ' DESC';
            }
        }

        if (!empty($limit))
        {
            $query .= ' LIMIT ' . $limitBegin . ', ' . $limit;
        }

        $result = $this->_sendQuery($query);

        $resultArray = array();

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            $resultArray[] = $row;
        }

        if ($monitoring) 
        {       
            // If monitoring is activated, echo the query
            echo $query;
        }
        return $resultArray;
    }
```

I want to use this line "while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))"
Please advice!

Comment: What prints var_dump($result)?

Comment: Your `select()` callback already collects an array using `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. Why do you think you would need to invoke it afterwards again?

Answer (score 5):

Your `select` method is returning an `array`, not a `resource`. This means that `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is right to complain.

The good news is that the `select` method is returning an array of results, which means you can replace `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` with

```
foreach($result as $row)
```

Answer (score 0):

That `select()` method clearly performs the query and then returns an array of results.  Why would you expect to be able to (or even need to) take that array and do a `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` on it again?

I think you can just iterate directly over `$result` like this:

```
$modelmake = $_POST['model_make'];
$result = $db->select('car_information','*', 'Model_Make LIKE \'%$modelmake%\''); 
foreach ($result as $row)
    echo 'Model'.$row['model_make'];
}
```

It should also be pointed out that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.